# Visual studio 2015 compile error: CS0570 is not supported by the language

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, visual-studio-2015, unmanaged

Migrating to VS2015, I encountered a compilation problem.
No change on projects' target framework, they remain .net 4.5

The compiler seems not recognize the types of parameters

```
void BootstrapOIS(List<long>^ %resultDates, List<double>^ %resultRates,
    const long tradingDate, /*const*/ List<int>^ periodNumbers,
    /*const*/ List<String^>^ periods, /*const*/ List<double>^ swapsRates,
    /*const*/ List<long>^ hol);
```

> Error CS0570  'BootstrapWrapper.BootstrapOIS(ref ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
>   is not supported by the language
>
> The referenced assembly:
>
> - Bootstrap, Version=1.0.4918.15400, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=b007f9158e880332
> - Global type:
> - Architecture:   x64
> - This assembly contains unmanaged code.
> - Runtime: .NET 4.0

The compilation went well with VS2013.

Comment: Try removing and readding the reference. I've had this happen and that corrected it for me.

Comment: @dman2306 : thanks for your reply. Tried, but does not seem to be working.

Comment: It happens when you mix standard C++ types and CLR ones. Can you give us the C++/CLI signature ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing standard and CLR types in your declaration. The generated code (from ILSpy) is the same but it chokes when using it from C#.

Using only CLR types in the signature seems to work:

```
void BootstrapOIS(List<Int64>^ %resultDates, List<System::Double>^ %resultRates,
    const Int64 tradingDate, List<Int32>^ periodNumbers, List<String^>^ periods,
    List<Double>^ swapsRates, List<Int64>^ hol);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar problem--supposedly Microsoft has an open bug on this.

Try removing the "const" declaration, and change tradingDate to an Int64 variable. If that resolves it then, congratulations, you have a successful workaround.